# How to split text into columns?

Tags: python, ascii

[image]

I want to split these ascii characters into 4 columns so it will look more convenient.. Uploaded a picture as an example..

```
for i in range(1,121):
    a = chr(i)
    print(str(i)+". "+str(a))
```

I have tried the .format or split(), but they don't seem to work as intended

Comment: You're going to have to figure out which characters go on the same line, and if they can be printed. For example, `chr(10)` is the newline charachter, which will break your formatting when printed. What would you do in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

Because `print` prints line-by-line, we're going to have to figure out which characters go on the same line, and then format those into a string. Since some characters are not printable, we'll have to replace them, especially characters like `"\n"` and `"\t"`, which would break our formatting. Luckily, python provides a [`str.isprintable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.printable) method that tells us exactly this. If a character is not printable, I've replaced it with an uppercase `X` (but you can choose any other character you want).

Next, we need to play with string formatting. [Here's a cheatsheet](https://www.pythoncheatsheet.org/cheatsheet/string-formatting) that describes the f-string syntax I've used. E.g., `f"{num:>3}"` formats the integer `num` into our string, right justified to three places. Similarly, `f"{disp_str:<10}"` formats the string `disp_str`, left-justified to a length of 10

The last thing to note is the use of the argument `end=""` in `print()`. The default value of this argument is `"\n"`, which means `print` adds a newline after whatever we ask it to print. Since we don't want that after each column, we add `end=""` (which tells python to add nothing after the argument to `print`). After all columns are done, we print nothing, but let it add the default newline, which takes us onto a new line in the terminal.

```
n_cols = 4
n_rows = 30

for row in range(n_rows):
    for col in range(n_cols):
        num = row + n_rows * col       # Find which character goes in this row/col
        char = chr(num)                # Get the ascii character
        if not char.isprintable(): 
            char = "X"                 # If it is not printable, replace it with a glyph for display
        disp_str = f"{num:>3}. {char}"      # Format num and char into a string
        print(f"{disp_str:<10}", end="") # Left-justify disp_str to 10 places. Do not print the default newline

    print("")   # After the row is done, we can print nothing (plus the default newline)
```

This gives the output:

```
  0. X     30. X     60. <     90. Z    
  1. X     31. X     61. =     91. [    
  2. X     32.       62. >     92. \    
  3. X     33. !     63. ?     93. ]    
  4. X     34. "     64. @     94. ^    
  5. X     35. #     65. A     95. _    
  6. X     36. $     66. B     96. `    
  7. X     37. %     67. C     97. a    
  8. X     38. &     68. D     98. b    
  9. X     39. '     69. E     99. c    
 10. X     40. (     70. F    100. d    
 11. X     41. )     71. G    101. e    
 12. X     42. *     72. H    102. f    
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To print multiple characters on the same line you will need to either print multiple in one statement or alternatively change the default end `"\n"` to prevent the newline after each print statement.

Then you can perform a check to print a newline only after 4 characters have been printed.

The below code prints the characters left to right, and then down.

```
for i in range(1,121):
    a = chr(i)
    print(str(i)+". "+str(a), end=" ")

    if i % 4 == 0:
        print()
```

I believe you may see some formatting issues due to printing some ASCII characters, however.

Comment: This prints consecutive characters in different columns, which doesn't seem like what OP wants.